# Create a python file with hardcoded array from a CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `CSV` and I would like to create a python **file** from it with array of `dics` inside.
Any search on how to do that bring me to using Pandas to create a dic **in memory**.

I need to create a **physical** file `name.py` in my project, and inside to have a code:

```
data = [{key:value},{key:value},...] # from my csv. Can have any other structure like dics in dic
```

I can start with this :

```
df = pd.read_csv ('index/index.csv')
```

Comment: That's a great start. Next: open a file called "name.py" for writing

Comment: thanks not sure if you are cynical? I need to create an actual *code* only one time, that stay there forever, like an actual file with text/code array.

Comment: Yes, and you said that code needs to be in "name.py". Do you know how to write to a file? If so, show it in your code. If you don't know, you might clarify in your question that you don't know how to open a file for writing.

Comment: Do you know how to get data from `df` and print the contents of `df`? If so, show it. If you don't know, please clarify in your question that you don't know how to get the data out of the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.to_dict('records')` generates output in the format that you want, I think

so it could look like

```
with open('name.py', 'w') as f:
    records = df.to_dict('records')
    print(f'data = {records}', file = f)
```

### Edit

to print each record on a separate line you can do something like

```
records = df.to_dict('records')
with open('name.py', 'w') as f:
    print('data = [', file = f)    
    for record in records:
        print(f'    {record},', file = f)
    print(']', file = f)
```

Comment: worked! that's beautiful. But it is in a single row, how can I make it more readable? like having each dic in a single line of code?

Comment: as I assume you want this to be valid Python, arbitrarily inserting line breaks is dangerous. You can do things like printing each dictionary  `{...}` on a separate line but not much beyond that

Comment: sorry for being dumb but how can I print each dic in each line? I will have to loop every line of this file? can you show?

Comment: pls see my edit

Comment: yea made it at the end, thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can return a generator of the rows you have in your dataframe using `iterrows()` method (you can check the document [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html))

```
data_generator = df.iterrows()
```

2. Then you can convert it to a list of tuples (index, row)

```
data_list = list(data_generator)
```

3. Then extract the rows only from your list of tuples and it will be on pandas.Series format (you can check the document from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html))

```
rows = [item[1] for item in data_list]
```

4. Then convert the pandas Series row to a dictionary

```
data = [item.to_dict() for item in rows]
```